# How to combine three different text patterns For Word Find Wildcards

Tags: regex, vba

I'm new to the concept of REGEX and couldn't figure out how to use it properly in my VBA code.
I want to extract all strings that have the following formats:

```
AMT.xxx.xx.xxxxxx
AMT.xxx.xx.xxxxx
AMT.xxx.xxxxxx
AMT.xxx.xx.xxx.xxx

where Xs are numbers.
```

I tried this line and couldn't get the last two patterns.

```
 With findRange.Find
         .Text = "AMT.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2,}.[0-9]{5,}"
```

I tried to include the last two patterns using the OR(|) operator but it seems like it's not working.

```
 With findRange.Find
         "AMT.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2,}.[0-9]{5,} | AMT.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{6} 
          | AMT.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}"
```

How do I update my code to include all four patterns?

Thanks.

Comment: OP do you just need to extract a list of string within a range that matches the above 4 patterns?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have this line ".MatchWildcards = True" right after the regex and wonder if this is an issue.

Comment: and what do you need to do with the list of matched strings? Do you actually need the location of where it's found or what? (This is a question for VBA on Word right?)

Comment: Yes, it's VBA on Word. I just need to get a list of all strings whose pattern is one of the four.

Comment: Pattern in Word Find/Replace is very limited so you can try `AMT\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}[0-9\.]{1}[.0-9]{3,7}`, it should match the above 4 format but could potentially catch some other format due to the inability to match the later part of the string using `zero or more occurrences`. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm If the location of where the string is found does not matter, you should use VBA regex (some [reference](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/))

Comment: `AMT\.[\d]{3}\.(?:[\d]{6}|[\d]{2}\.(?:[\d]{5,6}|[\d]{3}\.[\d]{3}))$`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uPas92/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must use Word Find with wildcard matching, Try this pattern:

`AMT\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}[0-9\.]{1}[.0-9]{3,7}`

It should match the above 4 format but could potentially catch some other format due to its inability to match the later part of the string using zero or more occurrences.

Reference - https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

Matches all the cases that you've mentioned in your question

`AMT\.\d{3}\.(?:\d{2,}\.?)+`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lEoUb4/1)**

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Thanks and sorry that was a typo. I've tried it but it's still not catching the last two patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It can probably factor down to this

```
AMT\.\d{3}\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{3}(?:\d{2,3}|\.\d{3})|\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/WtEvjf/1